# Узнать о клике на другие окна из приложения на JAVA

Tags: javafx, gui, awt, java, swing

Как можно узнать о клике на другие окна других приложений (например на броузер)
из приложения на JAVA и различную информацию об этом приложении (на которое кликнули): размер экрана, положение относительно верхнего левого угла.

т.е. есть запущенное приложение свернутое в трей на java, мы кликнули на броузер и в приложении возникло некое событие с информацией о приложении на которое кликнули.

Answer (score 2):

На чистой Java - никак.

Только в пределах приложения (то есть на всех "окнах" приложения).

Для общесистемного перехвата нужн native-библиотека.. А это уже как-то не по Javа'вски))
Но вы можете порыться в google с запросом "java system hook mouse".